# Multiple Form Submit - Array disappeared

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to run a foreach loop through an array of data from a multi form.
I am storing the data in `$_SESSION[]`, however when i get the to end of the form after the submit i cannot loop through it, it only has one value.

HTML

```
 <form action="professionalCourses.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="education1" > 

<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">

<div class="form-group">

<label for="complete[]"></label>
<select name="complete[]" id="">
<option value="Inompleted">Inompleted</option>
<option value="Completed">Completed</option>
</select><br>

<label for="year[]">Year Obtained</label>
<input type="text" name="year[]" id=""><br>

<label for="Institution[]">Institution</label>
<input type="text" name="Institution[]" id=""><br>

<label for="nameofQual[]">Name of Qualification</label>
<input type="text" name="nameofQual[]" id=""><br>
</div>

</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue"><br><br>
```

PHP - Variable Storing

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
// Check if file was uploaded without errors 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $_POST['complete'] = $_SESSION['complete'];
  $_POST['year'] = $_SESSION['year'];
  $_POST['Institution'] = $_SESSION['Institution'];
  $_POST['nameofQual'] = $_SESSION['nameofQual'];


    }
}
```

PHP - After Submit - Loop 1

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
// Check if file was uploaded without errors 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

 foreach ($_SESSION['complete'] as $key => $value) {
           echo $value.'<br>';
        }
}

}
```

PHP - After Submit - Loop 2

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
// Check if file was uploaded without errors 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

 $complete = $_SESSION['complete'];

    foreach ($complete as $key => $value) {
       echo $value;
    }
}

}
```

PHP - For Loop

```
$complete = $_SESSION['complete'];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($complete); $i++) {
            if($i == 1) echo $complete[$i];
        }
```

ERRORS Foreach

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

ERRORS For

Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

What am i Doing wrong, seems like the data has been lost, if i do the loops on the page after the form above it works perfectly, but not at the end of the form.

Comment: Your assignments are backwards: `$_POST['complete'] = $_SESSION['complete'];` should be `$_SESSION['complete'] = $_POST['complete']`

Comment: There is no code here which stores anything in the session. Which lines do you believe are supposed to be responsible for doing that job? As Barmar says, it's possible that some of your statements are simply the wrong way round (so that they are reading _from_ the session, not assigning _to_ it).

Comment: @ADyson the rest of the values are working, i have a session_start(); at the top

Comment: rest of what values, exactly? "complete" is the only one you try to loop through later. But regardless of that, there is **no code** in your example which stores **anything** in the session.

Comment: @ADyson The code that's supposed to store in the session is presumably the lines with the backward assignments.

Comment: @TaariqSolomons If that doesn't fix it, the problem is somewhere else in the code.

Comment: @Barmar yeah I get it, I'm just trying to make the point, seeing as OP has already claimed to you that switching them somehow didn't achieve anything. Maybe that's not the only bug.

Comment: Check your log for `Headers already sent` errors. That will prevent session variables from being set.

Comment: Also why do you keep repeating the `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") { 
// Check if file was uploaded without errors 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){` tests? It should only be necessary to do that once really, unless for some reason you are separating the different bits of processing into totally separate sections of code, or separate files even - but then it's not clear why that would be useful either.

Comment: And it's not really clear how this counts as a "multi" form really either - there's only one `<select name="complete[]"` shown in your HTML, for example, so only one value for that can be submitted at once. Are you actually just asking the user to submit the same form repeatedly? Because that's not the same as a form which accepts multiple values for the same parameter name simultaneously. And if that's what's happening, then even if you switch your variable assignments correctly, it'll still completely overwrite the session value each time with a single value.

Comment: I used Jquery to allow the user to add more fields, `'$("#addMore").click(function(){   
    $(".form-group:last").clone().appendTo(".wrapper");  
});`  and it multi as there are more than one page the user has to complete

Comment: @Barmar Thank you it solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

Put everything inside just one .
In each input, you define how it will be:

```
<label for="Institution-form1">Institution</label>
<input type="text" name="Institution[form1]" id="Institution-form1">
```

Note that "form1" will be the unique ID for each  session displayed in your code.